# Symbols generated by variadic templates and GDB

Tags: c++, templates, gdb, variadic-templates

A while back, I posted a question regarding the scalability of variadic templates at large ([Scalability of variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047347/scalability-of-variadic-templates)), and it seemed at the time that there was no clear practical limit. Over time, I have noticed one clear drawback however, that is, the overwhelming number of symbols generated by the various instantiations. This is particularly problematic with GDB, which tries to load each of these symbols, thus resulting in a particularly large memory usage (several GB in my case).

Any idea how to work around this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe these are of some help? [strip](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strip) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/c-c-gcc-ld-remove-unused-symbols)

Comment: This isn't really a drawback of variadic templates per se. If you instantiate ten different specializations of a variadic template you won't get any more symbols or debug info than if you wrote ten separate class templates and instantiated them. The only difference is that writing ten different templates by hand might make you realise it's a bad approach and there might be a better approach, i.e. variadics make it easier to be lazy. Which I suppose could be stated as "variadic templates don't kill debuggers, lazy programmers do" ;-)